# Sending data from multiple rows to multiple textboxes in c# asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webform that queries my database and returns data. The data returns to textboxes, and once it's returned, the data is to be editable and sent back to the database and saved as a new record. My issue is, I have one table queried (references) that has more than one record, up to 52 in some cases.

I don't want to create 52 textboxes in the case that the item with 52 references is searched for, as there is usually less than 5 and that would take too much space. So my question is, how can I get all the rows to return without having to create 52 textboxes?

Gridviews will not work, my manager says that is too many clicks for our employees to click through (edit/update/delete etc, and they may have to do it 52 times, which is obviously excessive).

```
SqlCommand com3;
String str3;
//item_detail code for options
str3 = "select * from item_reference r left join item_header h on h.item_header_id = r.item_header_id where d.option_order =2 and h.item_id ='" + cloneItemID.Text + "'";
com3 = new SqlCommand(str3, con);
SqlDataReader readerThree = com3.ExecuteReader();
if (readerThree.Read())
{
    refcodeTextBox.Text = readerThree["ref_code"].ToString();
    readerThree.Close();
}
else
{
    readerThree.Close();
}
```

Comment: You can use a GridView. By using columns of type TemplateField, you can add textboxes inside a grid that users can change without having to click buttons. You can have one central button above or below the grid that does then save all the changes by iterating over the grid rows.

Comment: Oh great, I will look into some research on that. My gridviews actually function as they should, I just need to have that one button control. So the changes in the textboxes would stay put if you switch from textbox to textbox, right?

Comment: Yes, you can change them at random like in a normal Grid in a desktop application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a GridView. By using columns of type TemplateField, you can add textboxes inside a grid that users can change without having to click buttons. You can have one central button above or below the grid that does then save all the changes by iterating over the grid rows.

Here is a very simple sample application.

This is the aspx part inside a normal page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="LastName,FirstName">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Street">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtStreet" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Street") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ZIP">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtZIP" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ZIP") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("City") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

This is the associated code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Fill the grid with data
        DataTable x = new DataTable();
        x.Columns.Add("LastName");
        x.Columns.Add("FirstName");
        x.Columns.Add("Street");
        x.Columns.Add("ZIP");
        x.Columns.Add("City");

        x.Rows.Add("Müller", "Fritz", "Amselweg 12", "77777", "Entenhausen");
        x.Rows.Add("Monroe", "Marylin", "5th Avenue", "12345", "New York");
        x.Rows.Add("Holmes", "Sherlock", "221 Baker Street", "1223", "London");

        GridView1.DataSource = x;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = "";

    // Iterate over data
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        string lastName = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["LastName"] as string;
        string firstName = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["FirstName"] as string;
        string street = (row.FindControl("txtStreet") as TextBox).Text;
        string zip = (row.FindControl("txtZIP") as TextBox).Text;
        string city = (row.FindControl("txtCity") as TextBox).Text;

        text = text + "<br/>" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(string.Format("{0} {1} now lives in {2} {3} {4}", firstName, lastName, street, zip, city));
    }

    Label1.Text = text;
}
```

What the grid looks like when loading the page:
[image: What the grid looks like when loading the page]
You can see, that in the columns Street, ZIP and City you have normal text boxes in each row.

After editing some values and clicking the button:

[image: After editing some values and clicking the button]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for taking the time to do that for me. Thank you kindly.